# Trouble echoing data - data being converted to 0

Tags: php

I feel this is something to do with my httpd setup for apache. I'm using mod_rewrite if that helps but I think that only effects the url.

It seems when I output some data such as:

```
$sMessage = 'Error';
echo $sMessage;
```

It works fine but when I do this:

```
$sMessage = 'Error';
echo '<p>'+$sMessage+'</p>';
```

It returns 0. Very odd!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string concatenation character in PHP is `.`, not `+`. `+` does a mathematical operation.
This should work:

```
$sMessage = 'Error';
echo '<p>'.$sMessage.'</p>';
```

Comment: @Haraldo I know how you feel. I get the same problem the other way round :)

Comment: Yep, JavaScript is complaining about dots all the time :-)